# Can a navigation use external URL to load views dynamically from the server?

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am learning react native. I was wondering if it is possible to develop react native app using react-navigation in such a way that the app can be dynamically updated. So following is what I have in mind:

The react native app available via app/play store will be just a "shell". This "shell" has the responsibility to fetch only those parts of the app that the user is interested in. Say, for instance, the app has five screens - Screen 0, Screen 1, Screen 2, Screen 3 and Screen 4. When the user launches the app, the "shell" will by default fetch Screen 0 from the server and render it. This Screen 0 has four buttons, Button 1, Button 2, Button 3 and Button 4. If the user selects Button 1 then Screen 1 is fetched from the server and rendered; if Button 2, then Screen 2 and so forth. If the user does not press, say, Button 4 then Screen 4 will not be fetched.

The advantage of this approach is that the app can be dynamically updated. The only part that needs to be published to the app/play store will be the "shell". Is this something possible with react native using react-navigation?